# Can IP range be made keys in Redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

Is it possible  that an ip range can be set as a key in a Redis. My requirement is that i have to fetch records based on ip address.
Now this ip address can be start_ip or end_ip or any ip falling in between it. I have to make to ip as the key.Can this be achieved

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just enclose it within double quotes

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan can you please show suppose I have ip range from 111.192.79.0 to 111.192.79.10.How this can be achieved

Comment: You can retrieve all the keys, sort them according to keys and store them in an array and finally slice the array to get your desired IP range. Do this in your node js

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan I am reading a csv file in which every record has startIp, endIp and some other details .I want to store the records in Redis in such a way that that records can fetched from keys.keys here are ip address which can be startIp or endIp or any ip falling between them.Could you please help with some snippet

Comment: Lokesh please have a look at [this](https://redis.io/commands/zadd)

Comment: If you post a link to your csv file, I can help. Or mail me at prasanthmaverick@gmail.com

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan Its a simple csv file with 0.5 million records.Nothing fancy in it.Reading the file is easy using Node fs..issue is how to store the data in Redis such that the fetch operation based on ip can happen efficiently

Answer (score 1):

If you know the starting and ending index of your IPs, you can do this

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(port, host);
client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Redis client connected');
    //insert your code for storing your csv data in an array
    var csv_array = ['127.0.0.1','127.0.0.2','127.0.0.3'];//store your IP in this way
    //for storing in redis
    for(var i=0,index=1; i<csv_array.length; i++,index++){
        client.zadd(['ipaddress',index,csv_array[i]],function(err,res){
            console.log("added"); 
        });
    }
    //for retrieving specify starting, ending index
    client.zrevrangebyscore(['ipaddress',startingIndex,endingIndex],function(err,res){
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

If you don't know the index values then just replace the retrieve part with this:

```
var IP_array = [];
var starting, ending;
client.zrevrangebyscore(['ipaddress','+inf','-inf'],function(err,res){
    IP_array.push(res);
});
starting = IP_array.indexOf('127.0.0.1');//staring IP range
ending = IP_array.indexOf('129.32.21.180');// ending IP range
console.log(IP_array.slice(starting, ending));
```

Comment: In Csv for every record I have  ip_start and ip_end.To query I will pass an ip.If this ip matches ip_start or it matches ip_end or it falls in between ip_start and ip_end then that particular record must be fetched

Comment: Can you show me a single instance of your csv file? I already asked you to provide the csv file but you did not provide it. I could improve my answer by looking at it.